# Removing key => value pairs from an array, but its not removing them

Tags: php, array-unset

I am trying to remove two key value pairs from an array, I am using the code below to segregate out the keys I don't want. I don't understand why it is not equating properly. if I remove the OR (`|| $key != 6`) it will work properly but I was hoping to have one if statement. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

```
$test = array( '1' => '21', '2' => '22', '3' => '23', '4' => '24', '5' => '25', '6' => '26'  );

foreach( $test as $key => $value ) {
    if( $key != 4 || $key != 6 ) {
        $values[$key] = $value;
        echo '<br />';
        print_r( $values );
    }
}

// Output
Array ( [1] => 21 [2] => 22 [3] => 23 [4] => 24 [5] => 25 [6] => 26 )
```

Comment: You're trying to segregate both 4 and 6 from the array? Use `&&` instead of `||`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the best way to do that:

```
$values = $test;
unset($values[4], $values[6]);
```

Assuming that you need a new array `$values`.  Otherwise remove them directly from `$tests`.

Reference here: http://php.net/unset

---

**The following is just for your own education in boolean logic, it's not the way you should do it.**

You need to change `||` to `&&`.  You don't want *either* in the result.  With logical OR, all of them will get through because `4 != 6` and `6 != 4`.  If it hits `4`, it will run like this:

> Are you not equal to 4?  Oh, you *are* equal to 4?  Well, the best I can do is let you though if you're not equal to 6.

If you change it to `&&`, it will run something like this:

> Are you a number besides 4 or 6?  No?  Sorry pal.

Comment: Thanks! I kept thinking that if its not 4 or 6 and got tripped up. I appreciate it!

Comment: I cant tell you how many times i have to refer back to your answer, you would think i would know by now! +1

Answer (score 7):

Someone's tripped over [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) again...

```
if( $key != 4 && $key != 6 ) {
```

Comment: Thanks for referencing the the pertinent law.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't really need the loop, this will do the same thing:

```
unset($test[4], $test[6])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is wrong. if you dont want to take key 4 and 6 then your condition should be like this

```
foreach( $test as $key => $value ) {
   if( $key != 4 && $key != 6 ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a native PHP function:

```
$values = array_diff_key ($test , array('4'=>'','6'=>''));
```

Comment: Great answer. I think this is the best way to remove specific keys from an array, its simple and does not require a loop.